# How do I correlate SensorEvent timestamp with other events in Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have been developing a set of internal apps and just got around to Lollipop testing (they were supposed to be retired long before the rollout). Parts of my apps involve correlating timing of events relative to sensor data. In the past, our usage devices have had the SensorEvent.timestamp value expressed relative to either elapsedRealtime or currentTimeMillis, but neither seem to work on a Nexus 5 with the Lollipop factory image. Does anyone know what the new timestamp is relative to?

Comment: From some tests I've done, the timestamps are related to none of the 3 available System clocks of Android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

They seem to be closer to elapsedRealtimeNanos() with an offset. Did you find anything else on this?